# Click and drag to select and move points on a SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg, drag-and-drop, html5-draggable

With a SVG with lines and points like this:

```css
svg line { stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px; }
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg">
<circle id="1a" cx="20" cy="20" r="3"></circle><circle id="1b" cx="20" cy="120" r="3"></circle><line id="1c" x1="20" y1="20" x2="20" y2="120"></line>
<circle id="2a" cx="20" cy="120" r="3"></circle><circle id="2b" cx="60" cy="80" r="3"></circle><line id="2c" x1="20" y1="120" x2="60" y2="80"></line>
<circle id="3a" cx="60" cy="80" r="3"></circle><circle id="3b" cx="100" cy="120" r="3"></circle><line id="3c" x1="60" y1="80" x2="100" y2="120"></line>
<circle id="4a" cx="100" cy="120" r="3"></circle><circle id="4b" cx="140" cy="100" r="3"></circle><line id="4c" x1="100" y1="120" x2="140" y2="100"></line>
<circle id="5a" cx="140" cy="100" r="3"></circle><circle id="5b" cx="100" cy="20" r="3"></circle><line id="5c" x1="140" y1="100" x2="100" y2="20"></line>
</svg>
```

is there a way with a HTML `<svg>` to be able to click and drag to select points? So that we can then mouse drag to move these points?

Before re-inventing the wheel, are there ways to do this directly with a `<svg>`?

[image]

For example, how to use the Drag and Drop API (see https://coursesweb.net/javascript/drag-drop-html5-attributes_t) to achieve this:

```
<tag draggable='true' ondragstart='handler(event)' id='draggable_elm'>Content</tag>
```

for SVG elements?

Comment: You'd have to write this yourself or find a library that implements it.

Comment: Would it be possible to just use a `draggable` attribute for the `circle` endpoints?

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Comment: Hey @Basj, Is there a reason you are using separate lines instead of a polyline? This'll give you a set of coordinates that can have anchor dots auto generated at each coordinate.  The initial simple math would be to calculate what points are in a selected range and then a simple mouseDown, mouseMove event to move the selected range.